# What's the best way to communicate the purpose of a string parameter in a public API?

Tags: c#, frameworks

According to the guidance published in [New Recommendations for Using Strings in Microsoft .NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973919.aspx), the data in a string may exhibit one of the following types of behavior:

1. A non-linguistic identifier, where bytes match exactly.
2. A non-linguistic identifier, where case is irrelevant, especially a piece of data stored in most Microsoft Windows system services.
3. Culturally-agnostic data, which still is linguistically relevant.
4. Data that requires local linguistic customs.

Given that, I'd like to know the best way to communicate which behavior is expected of a string parameter in a public API. I wasn't able to find an answer in the [Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613).

Consider the following methods:

```
   f(string this_is_a_linguistic_string)
   g(string this_is_a_symbolic_identifier_so_use_ordinal_compares)
```

Is variable naming and XML documentation the best I can do? Could I use attributes in some way to mark the requirements of the string?

Now consider the following case:

```
   h(Dictionary<string, object> dictionary)
```

Note that the dictionary instance is created by the caller. How do I communicate that the callee expects the IEqualityComparer<string> object held by the dictionary to perform, for example, a case-insensitive ordinal comparison?

Comment: I'd prefer not to complicate the library by using special dictionary classes or classes that wrap a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use a modified Hungarian convention (and I mean the [Joel-approved kind](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html)):

- Prefix `cs` for *case-sensitive* (non-linguistic)
- Prefix `ci` for *case-insensitive* (non-linguistic)
- Prefix `cil` for *culture-invariant linguistic*
- Prefix `csl` for *culture-specific linguistic* or *culture-sensitive linguistic*

The "i" and "s" have consistent implications here, even though they can mean two different things depending on the context, which is a helpful attribute.  "i" means "don't care" (about case/culture) and "s" means "do care".

Of course, as a disclaimer, I never do this, because for the vast majority of strings I deal with, the distinction between these types of strings is blurry at best.  But if they have semantic meaning to you, this would be a reasonable alternative to relying on XML docs.  Especially when you're using them as arguments to private methods, which most people don't write XML docs for.

Comment: I read Joel's post; I like his thoughts on Apps Hungarian.  I think I'll suggest this strategy unless someone else comes up with a better one. You're right on the mark about private methods, and I won't have to worry as much about lost .xml files.

Comment: I want to add that the real solution is a combination of Apps Hungarian and XML documentation, but since I mentioned XML documentation in my original question I'm going to give the checkmark to Aaronaught.

Answer (score 5):

Use the documentation syntax:

```
/// <param name="dictionary">
/// ... string is case sensitive ordinal ...
/// </param>
```

Comment: Yes, that is an answer, but is that the best I can do?

Comment: @Dave: Since that documentation is displayed by Intellisense, it should be fine.